# Exception has occurred: WebDriverException

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Someone tell me that what happen with my chromedriver ???

***This is my trace ***

```
Exception has occurred: WebDriverException
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.80,platform=Linux 4.9.230-76 aarch64)
  File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/utils/driver_utils.py", line 140, in create_driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
  File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/main.py", line 26, in main
    driver = create_driver(db.account)
  File "/home/odroid/Documents/python/crawling-worker/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

it means somewhere you are using send_keys(filepath) and the file doesn't exists in that path